# How transaction works in case of failure

Tags: scala, playframework, transactions, rollback

In the method below, how could I rollback all transactions when one fails?
Am I able to write all insert statements in a single transaction?

```
def save(types: List[admin]  ): Unit = {

    try {
      DB.withTransaction { implicit c =>
        val update = SQL("insert IGNORE into table1 (user_id, full_name, user_name) values ({user_id},{full_name},{user_name})")
        val batch = (update.asBatch /: types)(
          (sql, _type) => sql.addBatchParams(_type.user.id, _type.user.name, _type.user.login_id))
        batch.execute
      }
      DB.withTransaction { implicit c =>
        val update1 = SQL("INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 (user_id, role_id, is_enabled) values ({user_id},{role_id},{is_enabled})")
        val batch1 = (update1.asBatch /: types)(
          (sql, _type) => sql.addBatchParams(_type.user.id, _type.role_id, 1))
        batch1.execute
      }

      DB.withTransaction { implicit c =>
        val update2 = SQL("INSERT IGNORE INTO table3 (user_id, bu_id, role_id, is_enabled) values ({user_id},{bu_id},{role_id},{is_enabled})")
        val batch2 = (update2.asBatch /: types)(
          (sql, _type) => sql.addBatchParams(_type.user.id, 1, _type.role_id, 1))
        batch2.execute
      }

    } catch {
      case ex: Exception =>
        Logger.error("Exception : " + ex.getMessage)
        play.Logger.info("Exception" + ex.getMessage)
    }

  }
```

Comment: Yes you can put them all in one transaction.

Comment: The `DB` object is from Play, not from Anorm itself, which doesn't manage the connections/transactions.